# Is it possible to automatically add all the IDs from FXML to Controller in IntelliJ or other platforms

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I've started a new project in **JavaFX** in **IntelliJ** IDE. And I've lots of elements set on our **FXML** file. Manually adding all these ID's to the Controller is little difficult. So is there any easy way to add them to our Controller?

Comment: If you have some many IDs, this might be an indicator that the control should be split up: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/custom_control.htm

Comment: ... or that this UI is not a good candidate for FXML at all (this is especially true if, e.g., elements could be created in a loop). That said, if you're using SceneBuilder, iirc (it's a while since I used it) it has the option to create a stub controller class, which will include all the `@FXML`-annotated fields

Comment: Are you using SceneBuilder?  If so click on View -> Show Sample Controller Skeleton - that will allow you to copy and paste all the elements into your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Rightclick on the .fxml file --> FXML Helper --> Generate Controller --> Select access level for your controller variables

[FXML Helper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9Awu.png)